как сделать радио кнопки в телеграмме с aiogram v3
мне надо создать телеграм бота с меню и я хочу чтоб перед отправкой продукта в корзину человек мог выбрать модификаторы и собственно для модификаторов размера мне нужно ограничение чтоб можно было выбрать лишь 1
вот часть кода функции
def get_products_btns(
    *,
    level: int,
    category: int,
    page: int,
    pagination_btns: dict,
    product_id: int,
    product_mod:str,
    sizes: tuple[int] = (2, 2,1)
):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    prod_mod = json.loads(product_mod)
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад',
                callback_data=MenuCallBack(level=level-1, menu_name='catalog').pack()))
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Корзина ',
                callback_data=MenuCallBack(level=3, menu_name='cart').pack())) 
    for i in prod_mod:
        if 'см' in i['name']:
            result = i['name'][-6:] 
            keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{result} {i["price"]}₴',
                        callback_data=MenuCallBack(level=level, menu_name='add_to_moddificate', product_id=product_id , modificator = i).pack())) 
        else:
            keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{i["name"]}  {i["price"]}₴',
                        callback_data=MenuCallBack(level=level, menu_name='add_to_modificate', product_id=product_id , modificator_id=i['id'] , modificator_price=i['price'] , modificator_name=i['name']).pack()))
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Купити',
                callback_data=MenuCallBack(level=level, menu_name='add_to_cart' , product_id=product_id).pack())) 
    keyboard.adjust(*sizes)

